# How can reports be generated in Cucumber while running multiple test cases?

Tags: selenium, cucumber, report, cucumber-jvm

I am working on the automation of test cases with the Cucumber 4.0.0 framework and Selenium. Each test case corresponds to a Feature file.

When I run multiple test cases, the report is only generated until the end of the entire run. So what I would like is that when multiple test cases are run, the report is generated at the end of each test case and not until the end of all cases.

Comment: Which cucumber report you're using? Cucumber-Sandwich? If you opt for ExtentReport, you can have functions that flushes the report in @After hooks so that you can see the test cases report at runtime.

Comment: I use cucumber-reporting-2.3.0 @BhuvaneshMani

Comment: Then, i dont think you see realtime execution status of your tests. You can also see if you can setup Kibana dashboard and post the status to elastic. But thats huge, see if you can change your reporting to ExtentReport, you can achieve what you want.

Answer (score 1):

If  you have  some reporter being triggered with the configuration in an  `onComplete()` step, you could abstract that call and hook it up to other hooks such as `afterFeature()`

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).